# TensorFlow Classification Using Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, tensorflow

I need to utilize TensorFlow for a project to classify items based on their attributes to a certain class (either 1, 2, or 3).

Only problem is almost every TF tutorial or example I find online is about image recognition or text classification.  I can't find anything about classification based on numbers.  I guess what I'm asking for is where to get started.  If anyone knows of a relevant example, or if I'm just thinking about this completely wrong.

We are given the 13 attributes for each item, and need to use the TF neural network to classify each item correctly (or mark the margin of error).  But nothing online is showing me even how to start with this kind of dataset.

Example of dataset: (first value is class, other values are attributes)

```
2, 11.84, 2.89, 2.23, 18,   112, 1.72, 1.32, 0.43, 0.95, 2.65, 0.96, 2.52, 500
3, 13.69, 3.26, 2.54, 20,   107, 1.83, 0.56, 0.5,  0.8,  5.88, 0.96, 1.82, 680
3, 13.84, 4.12, 2.38, 19.5, 89,  1.8,  0.83, 0.48, 1.56, 9.01, 0.57, 1.64, 480
2, 11.56, 2.05, 3.23, 28.5, 119, 3.18, 5.08, 0.47, 1.87, 6,    0.93, 3.69, 465
1, 14.06, 1.63, 2.28, 16,   126, 3,    3.17, 0.24, 2.1,  5.65, 1.09, 3.71, 780
```

Comment: In non-convnets (like in the basic mnist example of TF) the image is actually just a list of numbers, so you can use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the data in a file, data.txt. You can use Numpy to read this:

```
import numpy as np
xy = np.loadtxt('data.txt', unpack=True, dtype='float32')
x_data = xy[1:]
y_data = xy[0];
```

More information: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Perhaps, you may need 'np.transpose' depends on the shape of your weights and operations.

```
x_data = np.transpose(xy[1:])
```

Then, use 'placeholders' and 'feed_dict' to train/test your model:

```
X = tf.placeholder("float", ...
Y = tf.placeholder("float", ...
....
with tf.Session() as sess:
....
       sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:x_data, Y:y_data})
```

Answer (score 0):

for this kind problem TensorFlow have an in depth tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough)
or in toward data science [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/)

if your looking for videos to start i think sentdex's tutorials on the titanic data-set 
is what your looking for although he is using k means to do the classification 
(actually I think his entire deep learning/machine learning playlist is great to start with)
you can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6jstahQp2A)

otherwise if your looking for basic how to start

first prepossessing:

try first separating the data into class labels and inputs (pandas lib should be able to help you with this)

make your class labels into a one-hot array

than normalize the data:

it looks like your different data attributes have wildly different ranges, make sure to get them all in the same range between 0 and 1

build your model:

a simple fully connected net should do the trick 
remember to make the output layer the same size as the number of classes you have

use an argmax function on the output of the finale layer to decide which class the model thinks is the proper classification